# Vuetify default carousel CSS selectors, for transition duration reduction

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-selectors, vuetify.js

[image][image]I need a transition that does not produce the dreaded image blinking for a v-carousel-item. Ideally it's a smooth and quick fade that would work for both transition and reverse-transition. I have tried all the transitions built in to Vuetify as well as a couple of custom ones but nothing works. My issue can be seen
[CodePen of the issue](https://codepen.io/Magiczne/pen/xxGYxyZ) and in a reported at [GitHub Vuetify Issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10809).

> ```
> <div id="app">
>   <v-app>
>     <v-carousel>
>       <v-carousel-item
>         v-for="(item,i) in items"
>         :key="i"
>         :src="item"
>         reverse-transition="fade-transition"
>         transition="fade-transition"
>       ></v-carousel-item>
>     </v-carousel>
>   </v-app>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Have you tried this workaround? https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10809#issuecomment-629468386

Comment: Yes I tried but the problem is it makes the entire v-carousel-item div disappear for me. I think it is because I have it in a v-tabs within a v-tabs so the position absolute argument messes with where the image is being displayed.

Comment: That's strange. This workaround targets the generated `.v-window-item` class elements, that are inside `.v-carousel` class element. With `absolute` position it should snap to the first positioned (not static) ancestor element, which is the v-carousel itself. Could you screenshot your DOM and styles after applying the CSS?

Comment: Here it is. Is it normal that the display is set to to none, maybe that is where the problem lies.

Comment: `display: none;` is applied to the carousel items because of `v-for`, you can see multiple hidden `v-window-item` classe divs, and there should be one, which is not hidden. Anyway, the CSS fix is applied to the element, so look for the [_the first positioned (not static) ancestor element_](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp#midcontentadcontainer). It should be the parent-parent `v-carousel` classed div, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Is this carousel set to cycle? Can you show the code for it? There might be some other code related to modifying it's behavior.

Comment: Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zed_at_home/pen/ExPKWWZ) showing the flicker issue, and the fix. Your carousel is inside tabs, but that shouldn't change how the fix works, unless the `v-carousel` is inheriting it's position, and it is not `position: relative`

Comment: <v-carousel 
      :cycle="playPause"
      interval=3000
      v-model="run"
      height="auto"
      hide-delimiter-background
      show-arrows-on-hover 
      >
      <v-carousel-item
      transition="v-fade-transition"
      reverse-transition="v-fade-transition"
        v-for="(item,i) in items"
        :key="i"
        >
        <v-row>
          <v-spacer/>
            <img width="75%" :src="item.src"/>
          <v-spacer/>
        </v-row>
        
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>

Comment: Mr. Zed do you mind contacting me on Discord StuckDuckF#6702 ?

Comment: `height="auto"` breaks it, remove it. `v-model` is probably not needed, since the `cycle` prop can handle. Look at my updated pen: https://codepen.io/zed_at_home/pen/VweapGB?editors=1000

Comment: OMG you are right about the auto height breaking it, but how would I fit the image in responsively? Is there a workaround to make it auto adjusting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215788/discussion-between-yordan-radev-and-zed-home).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a CSS workaround for the currently open issue:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10809#issuecomment-629468386

```
.v-carousel .v-window-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/zed_at_home/pen/VweapGB?editors=1000) with the workaround, inside vertical `v-tabs`.

Comment: OMG you are right about the auto height breaking it, but how would I fit the image in responsively? Is there a workaround to make it auto adjusting?