# Vuetify Responsive Carousel Images inside v-tabs

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, responsive-design, vue-component

[image][image]

I was trying to get a responsive carousel with a working fade transition but quickly found out that if you have your height set to auto you mess up the transition (next image blinks underneath) and if you don't you lose responsiveness [StackOverflow Question About this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315211/vuetify-default-carousel-css-selectors-for-transition-duration-reduction). Right now I am trying to figure a way to get both the transition (first image where image is cropped but transitions perfectly) AND the responsiveness (second image where the image is responsive and fills the div with height auto but the transition is not right) right and it has been suggested that I should wrap them and let the grid figure it out. I need a little help with this.

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="1">
    <v-btn icon large @click="toggle">
      <v-icon>{{icon}}</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-col>
  <v-col>
    <v-slider 
      color="light-green" 
      thumb-color="light-green accent-4"
      thumb-size="30"
      track-color="light-green accent-4"
      v-model="run" 
      max="2"
      :tick-labels="ticksLabels"
      tick-size="6"
      ticks/>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
<v-carousel 
  :cycle="playPause"
  interval=3000
  v-model="run"
  hide-delimiter-background
  show-arrows-on-hover 
  >
  <v-carousel-item
    transition="fade-transition"
    reverse-transition="fade-transition"
    v-for="(item,i) in items"
    :key="i"
    >
    <v-row>
      <v-spacer/>
      <img width="75%" :src="item.src"/>
      <v-spacer/>
    </v-row>

  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
<v-card>
  <v-card-text>
    {{ sampleText }}
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

Comment: Hi! Make a working codepen with only the relevant markup and data. Here is a template: https://codepen.io/zed_at_home/pen/RwrabWz

Comment: I made [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/StuckDuckF/full/WNrwmoM) but some wierd reason it does not center the image and since I do not have a pro account I used the images from your codepen but in my case it would square images. The codepen still demonstrates how if you half screen the app you get a different and unwanted result.

Comment: @ZedHome I edited the question and added an image. The first image is with your fix where the transition is fine but the image gets cut off, while the second image is where I have a responsive div but the transition was off.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215788/discussion-between-yordan-radev-and-zed-home